# Configuring HTTPS to a Web Service kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I just **installed** the **kubernetes dashboard**. I would like to access it in **HTTPS** and not in HTTP. Unfortunately when I enter the URL https://10.109.0.xx:6443
 I have an error telling me that the connection is not secure. 
And I would just like to avoid this kind of mistake. 
Do you have any idea how I can fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: This is fully expected. You have an HTTPS connection but the certificate is not a globally trusted certificate as you are just running a local service. The French text says "the owner has not configured their website properly"  - and in this case you are the website owner. So if you trust what you've done you should hit "Advanced" and accept the certificate.

Comment: i know but i wouldn't click on Advanced  and accept the certificate.

Comment: I wouldn't want to have this message . Because unfortunathely it block me with helm :(

Comment: If you have a problem with helm you should probably mention that in the question, please make sure your code is [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands now it's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

so when i want to run **helm ls --tls** i get the error **certificate signed by unknown authority** as you can see below

I have succeeded to signa URL **https://xxx.cloud.net/** to go directly to the kubernetes dashboard .

```
# helm ls --tls 
Error: Get https://10.109.0.xx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dhelm%2Cname%3Dtiller: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "crypto/rsa: verification error" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "kubernetes")
```

Comment: I just identified the real problem.  The port **443** is signed but the API port **6443** isn't . Both of them they have the same URL https://xxx.cloud.net:443 & https://xxx.cloud.net:6443